# What did the kings and aristocrats in Europe use before toilet paper was introduced?

Tags: everyday-life

The current news of people hoarding toilet paper made me wonder what could be used instead and history should be able to provide some good answers since this is a universal human need!

Historically, poor people used whatever at hand for toilet paper, leaves, sticks, moss and so on (and later on, news paper) - but **what did the rich, kings, aristocrats and so on, use before toilet paper was introduced?**

Limit it to Europe and up until 1800 or so (but feel free to include Rome and Greece during antiquity).

Comment: [Xylospongium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylospongium) in Ancient Rome.  More generally, you might find [Toilet hygiene in the classical era](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233941685_CHRISTMAS_2012_Toilet_hygiene_in_the_classical_era) from the Christmas 2012 issue of the BMJ of interest.

Comment: Doesn't Wiki's [Toilet paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_paper#History) answer this? It says "wealthy people wiped themselves with wool, lace or hemp". If this isn't what you are looking for, can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: In days of old, when knights were bold, and paper wasn't invented, they wiped their arse on bits of grass, and went away contented (learnt by me 1957 approx).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for that. I just learned that "arse" rhymes with "grass", instead of "farce" as I used to think. So British "arse" and American "ass" are pronounced about the same?

Comment: In British 'received' pronunciation ('RP') as well as the London & South East accent, arse, grass, and farce all rhyme. My British arse is pronounced differently from an American ass, which rhymes with gas, mass, sass, etc.